# How to do Multiple Integration Test On Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't find much about how to create multiple integration tests.

Most YouTube tutorials were created before the null safety change or aren't to explicit on what do do.

I also tried the official docs, but nothing that useful came up.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did'nt you find integration-tests package useful for integration testing.
It's new package developed by google team.

https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests